# Finding screen size of camera view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` in my application. I am trying to get the camera view's size.

I used:

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

then I tried to get the `CGRect` from

```
    CGRect rect = picker.view.frame;
```

but the rect I got included the Controll Bar. I want to get the size of the view without the control bar. Anyone got a clue? I tried to search related topics, but so far didnt get anywhere.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can get control bar size and reduce it size from picker size right?

Comment: ya, thats exactly what i did. i will keep this if this is the only way. Thanks for reply :D.

Comment: could you tell us how you answered this please